# R Shiny Value Function not being triggered in reactivePoll

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am using reactivePoll to update my shiny dashboard. The first time I run the App it works fine. I have given a time interval of 1 minute for the data to be refreshed. After 1st minute the data is refreshed as expected. From the next minute the check function is triggered every 1 minute but the value function is not triggered and I do not get the latest data.

app.R

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinythemes)
 library(shinyWidgets)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(shinycssloaders)
 library(RPostgreSQL)
 library(pool)
 library(config)
 library(plotly)
 library(data.table)

Sys.setenv(R_CONFIG_ACTIVE = "xyz")
config <- config::get()

pool <- dbPool(
drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
host = config$host,
dbname = config$dbname,
port = config$port,
user = config$user,
password = config$password
)

onStop(function() {
poolClose(pool)
})

get_data <- function(pool) {
abc <- dbGetQuery(pool,"SELECT * FROM tablename") #Query to pull data
return(abc)
}
abc <- get_data(pool = pool)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(
title = 'Dashboard'
),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("pqr", tabName = "pqrs")
)
),
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(
    tabName = 'pqrs',
    hemaTab("pqr",abc = abc)
)
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
pollData <- reactivePoll(60000, session,
                         checkFunc = function() {
                           print("Entered Check")
                           Sys.time()
                           print(Sys.time())
                         },
                         valueFunc = function() {
                           print("Entered value")
                           get_data(pool)
                         }
 )
 order(input, output, session, data = pollData())
 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

pqrs.R

```
pqrs <- function(id, label = "pqr",pqrs) {
ns <- NS(id)
tabPanel('pqr',
       tabsetPanel(
       tabPanel('Downloads',
                fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(12,
                         DT::dataTableOutput("table")
                  )
                )
                )
       )
       )
  )
  }

order <- function(input, output, session, data) {
downloaddata <- reactive({
setDT(data) 
})
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( DT::datatable({
downloaddata()
})
)
}

I get the following result after running the app
"Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:53:06 EST"
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:53:07 EST"
[1] "entered value"
After 1 minute the dashboard gets refreshed and I get the following 
result
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:54:07 EST"
```

From the next minute the dashboard is NOT refreshed but the check function is triggered and time is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

> **tl;dr:** Try putting the `order()` function which calls `poolData()` inside an `observe()` function

I believe the problem is due to the fact that `reactivePoll`, contrary to how it appears to work, needs to actually be called inside a reactive environment in order to function properly.

When I run the below program I get the same problem as you:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput('text')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    pollData <- reactivePoll(600,session,
                             checkFunc = function() {
                                 print("Entered Check")
                                 Sys.time()
                                 print(Sys.time())
                             },
                             valueFunc = function() {
                                 print("entered value")
                                 return('x')
                             }
    )
    ord <- function(data) {
        print(data)
    }

    ord(isolate(pollData()))    # 1: Only triggers once
    # observe(ord(pollData()))  # 2: Triggers every time
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:39:35 PST"
[1] "entered value"
[1] "x"
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:39:35 PST"
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:39:36 PST"
...
```

But if I surround use the **Second Way** above (wrapping the `ord` call in an `observe` function), then it works as expected:

```
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:41:50 PST"
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:41:50 PST"
[1] "entered value"
[1] "x"
[1] "Entered Check"
[1] "2018-12-20 09:41:50 PST"
[1] "entered value"
[1] "x"
```

---

My guess is that what's happening is that `reactivePoll` works like any other `reactive*` expression: when it's called, it checks to see if it's invalidated. If it isn't, it returns the saved value; if it is, then it runs again and returns the updated value.

What I think is happening is that when the `checkFunc` detects a change, it doesn't tell the `valueFunc` to run directly, it just invalidates the `reactive*`. Once it's invalidated, the `valueFunc` runs when it's called. If you never call it (since you're only interested in side effects) then the `valueFunc` doesn't run.

---

In your case, I think (for whatever reason) the reactive environment created by `shinydashboard` functions like the first option: it is enough like a reactive environment that it can access the value of the `reactivePoll` function, but it doesn't trigger the `valueFunc`. By surrounding the `order` function in an `observe*` function, you'll keep checking and recalling the function.

Comment: I am calling the pollData(). It does not work as expected. I have not mentioned it previously. I included it in the code now. Thank you.

Comment: @user10596599 What is that `order` expression and why does it have `input`, `output`, and `session` in it? Also, you have to call `reactive`-expressions from a reactive context (ie. inside an `render*`, `observe*`, `isolate`, or `reactive*`). The line you added won't run, so I have no way to test it. Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: I am working with a shiny Dashboard. Instead of writing the code in the server function I use order function and call it where ever required. Yes I am calling all reactive expressions from reactive contexts.

Comment: @user10596599 I think you really need to provide a [mcve] of your problem. In the example you posted, `poolData()` is not being called from a reactive context, but without a [mcve] it's impossible to really see what's happening

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post to include the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me to autoupdate when underlying data changes in a postgres database:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

 # Application title
 titlePanel("Auto Update DB Table Viewer"),

 # Table Viewer
 DT::dataTableOutput("my_drugs_dt")
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
 library(magrittr)
 library(dplyr)

 # Get DB auth token
 rdshost <- "db.xxxxx.us-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com"
 username <- "my_user_name"
 region <- "us-xxxx-x"
 token <- reactiveValues(rds_token = system(paste0("aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname ", rdshost, " --port 5432 --username ", username, " --region ", region), intern = TRUE))

 # Establish DB connection
 myPool <- pool::dbPool(drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
                      dbname="sengine-data",
                      host=rdshost,
                      user= username,
                      password = isolate(token$rds_token),
                      bigint = "numeric")
onStop(function() { pool::poolClose(myPool) })

# Pull the data from DB
# Note: using the changelog timestamp from the database would be the best way to do checkFunc.  
#helpful: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-info.html
#or this one: SELECT * FROM pg_last_committed_xact() https://www.tutorialdba.com/2017/11/postgresql-commit-timestamp-tracking.html
#This is how to modify the parameter in rds: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-query-logging/
mysource_drugs <- reactivePoll(intervalMillis = 1000, 
                               session = NULL,
                               checkFunc = function(){
                                   conn <- pool::poolCheckout(myPool)
                                   mod_stamp <- RPostgres::dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT timestamp FROM pg_last_committed_xact()")
                                   pool::poolReturn(conn)
                                   return(mod_stamp)
                               }, 
                               valueFunc = function(){
                                   myPool %>%
                                       dplyr::tbl("drugs") %>%
                                       dplyr::collect()
                               }
)
output$my_drugs_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mysource_drugs()
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```